# Implementing KendoUI grid search with dataSource filtering

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm not sure if i'm doing this correctly, but I want to filter ('search') kendo ui grid based on one input's value. However, I want to search two fields of the grid, based on only one input.

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
        logic: 'or',
        filters: [
            { field: 'lastName', operator: 'startswith' },
            {
                logic: 'or',
                filters: [
                    { field: 'lastName', operator: 'startswith', value: viewModel.searchValue },
                    { field: 'address', operator: 'startswith', value: viewModel.searchValue }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

html:

```
<input data-bind="text: searchValue" />
```

Two questions, how do I achieve this, and how do I trigger the filtering? Right now, input value is only bound to viewModel's property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the bound value to update the filter change it to:

```
viewModel.get('searchValue')
```

Full code:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
    logic: 'or',
    filters: [
        { field: 'lastName', operator: 'startswith' },
        {
            logic: 'or',
            filters: [
                { field: 'lastName', operator: 'startswith', value: viewModel.get('searchValue') },
                { field: 'address', operator: 'startswith', value: viewModel.get('searchValue') }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```